# Printing the values inside a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples. For example: `[("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]`. I need to display it in a simple way. For example: `"your name is: A", "Your id is: 100"`.

If anyone can find a solution for this, it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is to create a function that works for one of the elements in your list. So you'll need something like:

```
showDetails :: (String, Int, Int) -> String
showDetails (name, uid, _) = "Your name is:" ++ name ++ " Your ID is: " ++ show uid
```

Then you would apply this function to each element in the list, which means you want to use the mapping function:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So, if your list is called `xs`, you would want something like:

```
map showDetails xs
```

This obviously gives you a result of type `[String]`, so you might be interested in the `unlines` function:

```
unlines :: [String] -> String
```

This simply takes a list of strings, and creates a string where each element is separated by a new line.

Putting this all together, then, gives you:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails $ [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single tuple, just pattern match all the elements, and do something with them. Having a function that does that, you can use `map` to transform the entire list.

```
import Data.List (foldl')

show_tuple :: (Num a, Num b) => (String, a, b) -> String
show_tuple (name, id, something) =
    "Your name is:   " ++ name ++ "\n" ++
    "Your ID is:     " ++ (show id) ++ "\n" ++
    "Your something: " ++ (show something) ++ "\n\n"

-- transforms the list, and then concatenates it into a single string
show_tuple_list :: (Num a, Num b) => [(String, a, b)] -> String
show_tuple_list = (foldl' (++) "") . (map show_tuple)
```

The output:

```
*Main Data.List> putStr $ show_tuple_list [("ab", 2, 3), ("cd", 4, 5)]
Your name is:   ab
Your ID is:     2
Your something: 3

Your name is:   cd
Your ID is:     4
Your something: 5
```

Comment: I am trying to take a list of tuples from file and display it in above mentioned way. But end up with getting an error saying "Type error in final generator".

Comment: If you use this solution, I'd be careful not to use "id" as a variable name, since it's commonly read as the identify function.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution

```
f (x,y,z) = "your id is " ++ (show y) ++ ", your name is " ++ (show x) ++ "\n"

main = putStrLn $ foldr (++) "" (map f [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])
```

OR  (by @maksenov)

```
main = putStrLn $ concatMap f [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]
```

Comment: `foldr (++) "" $ map` is basically `concatMap`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
get1st (a,_,_) = a
get2nd (_,a,_) = a
get3rd (_,_,a) = a

showTuples [] = ""
showTuples (x:xs) = "Your name is:" ++ show(get1st(x)) ++ " Your ID is: " ++ show(get2nd(x)) ++ "\n" ++ showTuples xs

main = do
    let x = [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]
    putStrLn . showTuples $ x
```