# How to transform $ expression to "regular" expression

Tags: haskell

I have read [Printing the values inside a tuple in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094993/printing-the-values-inside-a-tuple-in-haskell) and the solution works.
My intention with this question is understand what does `$` symbol by "translating" the code into a `$` free code.

```
showDetails :: (String, Int, Int) -> String
showDetails (name, uid, _) = "Your name is:" ++ name ++ " Your ID is: " ++ show uid

main = do 
    putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails $ [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]
```

How does `$` to tell showDetails to be applyed to list elements (the tuples)?
What is the `$` free version of that line?

Comment: The suggested duplicate -- while not a perfect match in title -- does cover this case and suggests `(putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails) [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is just function application:

```
f $ x = f x
```

Put like that, it looks useless. But it actually has a number of uses - and one of the most common ones comes from the fact that, as an infix operator, it has a lower precedence than any other. That is, when parsing the expression, Haskell takes everything to its left (that doesn't include another `$`) and everything to its right (likewise), and effectively puts both sides in parentheses.

This allows one to use `$` as a substitute for parentheses, since `f $ complicatedExpression` is the same as `f (complicatedExpression)`. So in your example:

```
putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails $ [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]
```

is identical to

```
(putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails) ([("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])
```

and the choice is purely stylistic preference. But most prefer `$`, particularly because multiple `$`s are much nicer than multiply-nested parentheses.

Comment: Hey Robin, and how ```(putStrLn . unlines . map showDetails) ([("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])``` does actually work? Why
```putStrLn . unlines . (map showDetails [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])``` it's not the correct answer? I think ghci should resolve the map sD [] before everything else.

Comment: @Nestoter `putStrLn . unlines . (map showDetails [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])` is a type error, because `.` expects a function type on either side, and `map showDetails [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)]` is not a function but a list of strings. In the correctly grouped version, you compose 3 functions to form another function - whose type is `[(String, Int, Int)] -> IO ()` - and apply it to a specific list of triples.

Comment: I should add that `(putStrLn . unlines) (map showDetails [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])` is fine. As is `putStrLn ((unlines . map showDetails) [("A",100,1),("B",101,2)])` - although I think that last version is clearly inferior to the others, due to additional nesting. But there are lots of ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Robin.